# Manual login user with devise

Tags: authentication, devise, sessionid, manual

Can anyone give an example or link to tutorial how can be implemented manual signin for users and get session_id.

I am porting an application from Rails 2 to Rails 3, that used before RestAuthentication. The new app uses devise, and I already managed to fix the sign-in/sign-out for admins. The application has one more model (users) that need to be authenticated.

I need to get session_id in order to pass it in the response, because the client is not browser, but mobile device.

Any links, ideas and examples are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used token id instead of session id. The token is re-generated each time when the session is expired or user log-outs.